# $(...).datepicker is not a function - JQuery - Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I'm trying to include the `datepicker` for Bootstrap but am getting the following error:

`Uncaught TypeError: $(...).datepicker is not a function`

I don't see why it's there. I've looked at other cases of this error, but none match mine.

**HTML:**

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>/js/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>/js/main.js"></script>

<div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group">
         <label for="geboortedatum">Geboortedatum:</label>
         <div class="input-group datepicker" data-provide="datepicker">
               <input type="text" name="geboortedatum" id="geboortedatum" class="form-control">
               <div class="input-group-addon">
                   <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span>
               </div>
         </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.datepicker').datepicker({
        format: 'dd/mm/yyyy'
    });
});
```

**UPDATE after adding JQuery UI**

It now looks like the following:

[image: update after adding JQuery UI]

Comment: you only include jquery but not jquery ui...

Comment: The plugin reference says `datetimepicker` and you are calling `datepicker`

Comment: Please check if you have included bootstrap datetimepicker twice(at the end most of the time) in a file by mistake..

Comment: @PrakashThete Nope, just once

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Not the right function name I think

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.datepicker').datetimepicker({
        format: 'dd/mm/yyyy'
    });
});
```

Comment: Tried using this, the icon at the end of the `input` just disappeared

Comment: Fixed it by using some of the CDN files instead of the local ones and by naming the function `datetimepicker`

Answer (score 13):

Need to include jquery-ui too:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Comment: Take a look to source here https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/ maybe you need a css stylesheet

Comment: That's the JQuery datepicker. I'm looking for the bootstrap datepicker

Comment: https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ you can check if all your dependencies are ok. Beware of conflicts bootstrap-jquery too!

Comment: I added all the necessary files. I can't find anything about adding the JQuery UI though

Comment: You are also calling wrong function as @François_Richard answer

Answer (score 3):

To get rid of the bad looking datepicker you need to add jquery-ui css

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to include jQueryUI

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.datepicker').datepicker({
        format: 'dd/mm/yyyy'
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script   src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.min.js"   integrity="sha256-xI/qyl9vpwWFOXz7+x/9WkG5j/SVnSw21viy8fWwbeE="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>/js/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>/js/main.js"></script>

<div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group">
         <label for="geboortedatum">Geboortedatum:</label>
         <div class="input-group datepicker" data-provide="datepicker">
               <input type="text" name="geboortedatum" id="geboortedatum" class="form-control">
               <div class="input-group-addon">
                   <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span>
               </div>
         </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had similiar problem. The quick fix I found is to change:

```
<div class="input-group datepicker" data-provide="datepicker">
```

to

```
<div class="input-group date" data-provide="datepicker">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

    var options={
            format: 'mm/dd/yyyy',
            todayHighlight: true,
            autoclose: true,
        };

    $('#datetimepicker').datepicker(options);

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by arranging the order in which your JS is being loaded.

You need to have it as jQuery -> datePicker -> Init js

Call your JQuery in your header, datePicker script in head below your jquery and Init JS in footer

Comment: If you put your init code in `.ready()` though, the load order shouldn't matter I don't think?

Comment: yes that shall work as well. but its always a good practice to have the right order

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following and it worked for me.

Import following **scripts** and **css** files as there are used by the **date picker**.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.4.1/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.4.1/css/bootstrap-datepicker3.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
```

The JS coding for the Date Picker I use.

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            // alert ('Cliecked');
            var date_input=$('input[name="orangeDateOfBirthForm"]'); //our date input has the name "date"
            var container=$('.bootstrap-iso form').length>0 ? $('.bootstrap-iso form').parent() : "body";
            var options={
                format: 'dd/mm/yyyy', //format of the date
                container: container,
                changeYear: true, // you can change the year as you need
                changeMonth: true, // you can change the months as you need
                todayHighlight: true,
                autoclose: true,
                yearRange: "1930:2100" // the starting to end of year range 
            };
            date_input.datepicker(options);
        });
    </script>
```

The HTML Coding:

```
 <input type="text" id="orangeDateOfBirthForm" name="orangeDateOfBirthForm" class="form-control validate" required>
 <label data-error="wrong" data-success="right" for="orangeForm-email">Date of Birth</label>
```